# NativeScript + Angular RadDataForm form source initialization issue

Tags: android, mobile, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have application in Angular 8. I've decided to migrate to NativeScript. I want create form with RadDataForm plugin.

```
...
<RadDataForm [source]="album">
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="owned"
        displayName="Do I Own This?" index="1"></TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="bandName"
        displayName="Band name" index="1"></TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="releaseYear"
        displayName="Release year" index="2">
        <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Number">
        </TKPropertyEditor>
    </TKEntityProperty>
</RadDataForm>
...
```

And this form works when album object is initialized in controller:

```
album = {owned: true, bandName: 'Crazy Band', albumName: 'Awesome Album', releaseYear: 1999};
```

But what I used to do in Angular was

```
Template:
<input [(ngModel)]='album.albumName'>

Controller:
album = {};
```

And it worked. In NativeScript, if object is not initialized, I have error:

```
RadDataForm._syncEditorsWithNativeEditors(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-dataform/ui-dataform.js:864:46)
at RadDataForm.reload(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-dataform/ui-dataform.js:761:14)
at RadDataForm._updateSource(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-dataform/ui-dataform.js:597:10)
at RadDataForm.createNativeView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-dataform/ui-dataform.js:537:10)
at ViewBase._setupUI(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:492:25)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:534:13)
at LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:20)
at ViewCommon.eachChild(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:1010:10)
at ViewBase._setupUI(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:10)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:534:13)
at ContentView.eachChildView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/content-view/content-view.js:70:7)
at ViewCommon.eachChild(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:1010:10)
at ViewBase._setupUI(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:10)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:534:13)
at LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:20)
at ViewCommon.eachChild(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:1010:10)
at ViewBase._setupUI(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:10)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:534:13)
at LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:20)
at ViewCommon.eachChild(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:1010:10)
at ViewBase._setupUI(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:10)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:534:13)
at ContentView.eachChildView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/content-view/content-view.js:70:7)
at PageBase.eachChildView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/page/page-common.js:126:36)
at ViewCommon.eachChild(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:1010:10)
at ViewBase._setupUI(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:10)
at ViewBase._addViewCore(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:432:12)
at ViewBase._addView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:421:10)
at FragmentCallbacksImplementation.onCreateView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/frame.js:689:13)
at FragmentClass.onCreateView(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/fragment.js:29:34)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1286)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1173)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1160)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1138)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1134)
at com.tns.FragmentClass.onCreateView(FragmentClass.java:54)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:793)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Playground code:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=00XiAP&v=4

Looks like bug, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: The source has to be initialised for RadDataForm to work. Its basically a plugin that helps you render your form from simple JSON configurations. If you are looking to build your own form, then you should use TextField for each attribute and define ngModel Or even use Reactive Forms. For checkboxes / radio buttons you will use plugins, for date picker you may use the built-in one or there are plugins for that too helps you build your date picker in various styles. RadDataForm is just all in one pack, you can't work with it like you would in Angular Forms, it has it's own APIs.

Comment: Thanks Manoj for your reply. As as frontend beginner I was sure that this is on Typescript level not framework level.

As long as for editing purpose it make sense to have object with initialized fields, for creating new object it would be nice to just pass empty object ( {} ).

If there is no way to do this now, maybe it's good idea to implement it as a new feature.